# How to skip a line of standard input?

Tags: c++, io

I am reading standard input, and want to stop skipping everything when I encounter a line that starts with an "a":

```
while(cin.peek() != 'a') {
    cin.get();
}
```

The only problem is, this also triggers if I have an a in the middle of the line.
I would try `cin.getline();` but I do not know the maximal length of the line. Is there a way to just go to the next line?

Comment: do you want stop skipping line when encounter special char?

Comment: As per [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), the canonical way would be `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it yourself, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    bool skip = true;
    for(std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);)
    {
        if(line.size() && line[0] == 'a')
            skip = false;
        if(!skip)
            std::cout << line<< std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n26V5pgLvGB0FE0T)</kbd>

This will ignore every line read, until it encounters a non-empty line, starting with `a` character. After that, it will *stop* skipping the lines read, and print every line.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `cin.get()` for `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), "\n")`.

Where `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is the maximum number of characters to be extracted and `"\n"` indicates that the value to stop to extract characters is the End Of Line (in addition to End Of File).